# jQuery anchor text reference not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have some anchors in HTML that have a class of "attrs":

```
<a href="#" class="attrs">sample</a>
```

I use this jQuery code to bind to those elements unobtrusively, and I am just doing a simple alert for test purposes:

```
$(".attrs").click(function() {
      alert($(this).attr('text'));
    });
```

This works just dandy in Firefox and Safari on Mac, fails unreliably in Firefox on Windows, and fails completely with an "undefined" in the alert on IE 7 & 8.

Note that if I change 'text' to 'href', then the alert comes up appropriately.

This seems like very simple, very basic code. I can not imagine why/how Windows browsers would behave incorrectly on something so simple. Can anyone offer anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

To get the text content from that anchor node.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that works reliably in all of them that I've checked.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `attr` function, and you don't have to use jQuery to get to `this`:

```
$(".attrs").click(function() {
      alert(this.text);
    });
```

[This seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/eykanal/P6vJv/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, thats because you don't have a `text` attribute for the `a` element.

Try this, if you want to alert the content of `a`:

```
$(".attrs").click(function() {
      alert($(this).html());
});
```